# Replacing os, boot loader not showing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I know many have asked this before but their problem is either: it directly boot to windows or does not boot at all. But my problem is slightly different and fixing this might also be different or easier.

I have dual boot LinuxMint & Windows and I replaced the old LinuxMint with the latest Ubuntu release. The installation was successful but it directly boot to Ubuntu and not showing the choices of OS's like before.

I thought installing grub and running update-grub will fix it but it didn't.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: try pressing shift right before grub comes up?

Comment: Which Windows version? We'll need to see the output of the [BootInfoScript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). Please use http://pastebin.com to post it.

Comment: Hi, it's here: http://pastebin.com/01VU9LDb

Comment: I've finally fixed it. What took me too long was that the installer couldn't detect my installation in my disk and I was not able to run /fixboot, until I found this http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/71363-system-reserved-partition-delete.html

I can't answer my own question yet. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally fixed it. What took me too long was that the installer couldn't detect my installation in my disk and I was not able to run /fixboot, until I found this http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/71363-system-reserved-partition-delete.html